# Nuget command line

Tags: build, nuget, azure-devops, command-line-interface, devops

I got an empty repository (project) in VSTS, to be very specific :
I don't have a visual studio solution or visual studio project.

what I want to do :
1. set up a build in VSTS
2. enable Nuget in the build process 
3. download a specific NuGet package (Newtonsoft.Json) in one of the build steps.
e.g. if I  had a package.config file then it would have the below line in it:

```
 <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" allowedVersions="[8,10)" targetFramework="net46" />
```

**Question:**

I know how to do the step 1 & 2 but I don't know how to do the step 3.

- I 'm looking for the specific commands that help me download the package during build process in VSTS.

anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Farzad J, any update on this thread, did my reply helped or gave a right direction?

Comment: I end up to host a file in GitHub and download it as a raw file via PowerShell.
But I couldn't find any solution that works without the need of solution & project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NuGet.exe to restore the package as follows -

1. Download NuGet.exe -

   `wget https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe -OutFile nuget.exe`
2. Run restore -

   `nuget.exe restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory <packages_directory>`
3. This will download the package into `packages_directory'.

But I would recommend you consider using [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) style of project that uses the project's csproj file to add package references and then you can use msbuild to restore packages and build - 
`msbuild project.csproj /t:"restore;build"`

Comment: thanks - I think that's the closest thing to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call [nuget.exe install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install) command in your code or cmd task, which is similar to the NuGet task: [VSTS-tasks/Tasks/NuGet](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/NuGet)

Answer (score 0):

FYI:
I end up to host a file in GitHub and download it as a raw file via PowerShell.
But I couldn't find any solution that works without the need of solution & project.